# "incorrect password" while trying to log on after deleting some applications

Tags: password

I unintentionally deleted some software like Ubuntu Software Center from the terminal in my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

Now when I try to log in to my account, it tells me that I typed an incorrect password. I want to at least download some valuable documents.

Comment: Please fix the `software center` first before trying to download any thing!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at fixing it from the Recovery mode, like [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword#The_Other_Way_Lucid).

If that won't work or is too difficult, you can boot in Live session from an Ubuntu usb stick or dvd, and then back up your data to a usb disk.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the previous comment suggests, using a live instance and copying the files might be your best option. If you've set up a root account password, you can login as user *root* and fix the problem by either installing the programs you removed or just to copy the files and/or fix your regular account. Unfortunately it isn't common users will manage the root group and it's unlikely yours is set. Try it if you can, best of luck!

Comment: I have set up a root password and can login as a user root. But I cannot copy my files to the usb drive or external hard drive since it doesn't show up on the terminal. Also can you elaborate me using live instance for copying the files. Since I need only the files in it I can reboot again my computer.

Comment: The live instance should be able to access all the connected drives, but in the case that it can't be done, you may need to do it with the command line. I'm not sure how your system is set up, so I can't really do much other than offer this *generic* advice.

Comment: Finally solved the problem. Using the live instance I could copy all my files into External Hard Drive. Thanks Alan Diggs, albert j and other for your help